# Error application loader 'CFBundleIcons': 'icon.png'

Tags: flash, air

I use Flash. To create icons and assets.car I used the site:
http://www.appuploader.net/appuploader/icontool.php

then I put the resulting file `assets.car` and icons in the directory where the main .fla is located.

My apps' descriptor XML file:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/31.0">
  <id>ru.host.mynameapp</id>
  <versionNumber>1.4</versionNumber>
  <filename>mynameapp</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>My Name App</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>mynameapp.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients></initialWindow>

  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <icon>
    <image152x152>Icon-152.png</image152x152>
    <image120x120>Icon-120.png</image120x120>
    <image76x76>Icon-76.png</image76x76>
    <image57x57>Icon.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>Icon-72.png</image72x72>
  </icon>

  <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
  <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
   ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>  

</application>
```

In Flash publish settings, only icons that are written in the apps' descriptor XML file are displayed.

I also tried to change the iPhone section to:

```
<iPhone>
    <assetsCar>Assets.car</assetsCar>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>AppIcon</string>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

When sending via application loader, I constantly get an error:
[error][2]

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to fix this error?

Comment: Hi please add the **text** of the XML (not add picture). You did it okay with _"the iPhone section"_ so copy/paste same full text of the `<application>` XML.

Comment: If I delete the icons section from the xml-file, then the application loader gives an error that there are no icons 152x152, 76x76, 120x120. So I need to delete all links to the icons, how to spell on the forums, then how to solve the issue with the three missing icons?

Comment: I have no experience with exporting iOS apps (only for Android, where this problem does not exist). Apple requires that you have these icon links so don't delete. Try to find solution for the next issue (_"no image found at path"_ etc). Did you involve XCode for icons & image process (as required by Apple)? See [Adobe AIR new features](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_28_air_28_release_notes.html#new_features) and scroll down to **iOS SDK Upgrade** section. Does it help you? I have no Mac. Maybe someone will help you soon that knows about this.

Comment: Also I see you have size **120** but [this link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2439817) says add also **80** for `icon-40.png`. Also look at your XML line `<image57x57>Icon.png</image57x57>` should it not be `<image57x57>icon-57.png</image57x57>`?

Answer (score 1):

I sent it successfully after I changed the names of the icon files in the apps' descriptor XML file.

Found the correct naming here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1686/_index.html

For example, the icon 120x120 should be referred to as Icon-60@2x.png

It turns out that the `assets.car` file is required so that the application icon is not empty. But having `assets.car` is not enough to successfully send an application through the application loader.
To download via the application loader I needed to change the apps' descriptor XML file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/31.0">
  <id>ru.host.myappname</id>
  <versionNumber>1.5</versionNumber>
  <filename>My App Name</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>My App Name</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>myappname.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients></initialWindow>

  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <icon>
    <image152x152>icon-76@2x.png</image152x152>
    <image120x120>icon-60@2x.png</image120x120>
    <image76x76>Icon-76.png</image76x76>
  </icon>

    <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
  <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>  
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your XML line:

```
<image57x57>Icon.png</image57x57>
```

Try setting as:

```
<image57x57>icon-57.png</image57x57>
```

PS: Posted here for readability. Let me know if it helps or else I need to delete as *"not working"*.

Comment: Yes, I will inform.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you should be including the following icon sizes. As VC.One mentions it's very important that the file names match what is in the app-descriptor. (case sensitive).

```
<icon>
        <image29x29>icons/Icon29.png</image29x29>
        <image57x57>icons/Icon57.png</image57x57>
        <image114x114>icons/Icon114.png</image114x114>
        <image512x512>icons/Icon512.png</image512x512>
        <image48x48>icons/Icon48.png</image48x48>
        <image72x72>icons/Icon72.png</image72x72>
        <image50x50>icons/Icon50.png</image50x50>
        <image58x58>icons/Icon58.png</image58x58>
        <image100x100>icons/Icon100.png</image100x100>
        <image144x144>icons/Icon144.png</image144x144>
        <image1024x1024>icons/Icon1024.png</image1024x1024>
        <image40x40>icons/Icon40.png</image40x40>
        <image76x76>icons/Icon76.png</image76x76>
        <image80x80>icons/Icon80.png</image80x80>
        <image120x120>icons/Icon120.png</image120x120>
        <image152x152>icons/Icon152.png</image152x152>
        <image180x180>icons/Icon180.png</image180x180>
        <image60x60>icons/Icon60.png</image60x60>
        <image75x75>icons/Icon75.png</image75x75>
        <image87x87>icons/Icon87.png</image87x87>
        <image167x167>icons/Icon167.png</image167x167>
    </icon>
```